# Can JPA Embeddable class contain an object reference?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to embed a class to another which contains object reference. I always get

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ...
```

exception. My question is there any way I can embed a class which contains object references, or embeddable classes only stores primitives.

I'm already tried @Target() annotation but not helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddable-override).

```
@Embeddable
public static class Publisher {

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Country country;

    //Getters and setters, equals and hashCode methods omitted for brevity
}


@Entity(name = "Book")
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(
        name = "ebookPublisher.name",
        column = @Column(name = "ebook_publisher_name")
    ),
    @AttributeOverride(
        name = "paperBackPublisher.name",
        column = @Column(name = "paper_back_publisher_name")
    )
})
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(
        name = "ebookPublisher.country",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ebook_publisher_country_id")
    ),
    @AssociationOverride(
        name = "paperBackPublisher.country",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "paper_back_publisher_country_id")
    )
})
public static class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Publisher ebookPublisher;

    private Publisher paperBackPublisher;

    //Getters and setters are omitted for brevity
}
```